# Appending array during Postgresql upsert & getting ambiguous column error

Tags: postgresql

When trying to do a query like below:

```
INSERT INTO employee_channels (employee_id, channels)
        VALUES ('46356699-bed1-4ec4-9ac1-76f124b32184', '{a159d680-2f2e-4ba7-9498-484271ad0834}')
        ON CONFLICT (employee_id)
        DO UPDATE SET channels = array_append(channels, 'a159d680-2f2e-4ba7-9498-484271ad0834')
        WHERE employee_id = '46356699-bed1-4ec4-9ac1-76f124b32184'
        AND NOT lower(channels::text)::text[] @>  ARRAY['a159d680-2f2e-4ba7-9498-484271ad0834'];
```

I get the following error

```
[42702] ERROR: column reference "channels" is ambiguous Position: 245
```

The specific reference to channels it's referring to is the 'channels' inside array_append.

channels is a CITEXT[] data type

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may need to specify the `EXCLUDED` table in your set statement.

```
SET channels = array_append(EXCLUDED.channels, 'a159d680-2f2e-4ba7-9498-484271ad0834')
```

When using the `ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE` clause the values that aren't inserted because of the conflict are stored in the `EXCLUDED` table.  Its an ephemeral table you don't have to actually make, the way `NEW` and `OLD` are in triggers.

From the [PostgreSQL Manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-insert.html):

> conflict_action specifies an alternative ON CONFLICT action. It can be either DO NOTHING, or a DO UPDATE clause specifying the exact
>   details of the UPDATE action to be performed in case of a conflict.
>   The SET and WHERE clauses in ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE have access to the
>   existing row using the table's name (or an alias), and to rows
>   proposed for insertion using the special excluded table. SELECT
>   privilege is required on any column in the target table where
>   corresponding excluded columns are read.
>
> Note that the effects of all per-row BEFORE INSERT triggers are reflected in excluded values, since those effects may have contributed
>   to the row being excluded from insertion.